# I am an Indian passport holder planning to visit Vietnam via Singapore. Which visa should I acquire?

Tags: singapore, multiple-entry, vietnam

I am planning to visit Vietnam this year. Since there are no direct flights from India to Vietnam I am planning to break my journey in Singapore. The plan for now is to take a round trip from India to Singapore and then a round trip from Singapore to Vietnam( no connecting flights).
I read online that multiple entry visa is required. My doubt is if I get a multiple entry visa for Singapore issued from India, will that be valid when I re enter Singapore from Vietnam ??

Comment: Do you happen to have a long term visa from Australia, Canada, Germany, Japan, New Zealand, Switzerland, the UK or the USA?

Comment: Well I have a long term visa from US n Canada..however the friend I am travelling with does not have it..so can you please tell us what needs to be done in both cases

Comment: Can someone please help us with this situation??

Answer (score 1):

As your itinerary takes you through Singapore on both legs of your journey, you would need to apply for [an entry visa](https://www.ica.gov.sg/visitor/visitor_entryvisa), and its validity determined by the itinerary you present upon application (for your onward and return). Booking two round trips tickets, India-Singapore and, separately, Singapore-Vietnam, creates a layover or stopover.

You mention breaking your journey; you don't say how, whether it would be for just long enough to take the next flight, a layover of a matter of hours, or a few days, a stopover. Either way, you would not be able to take advantage of Singapore’s [Visa Free Transit Facility](https://www.ica.gov.sg/enteranddeparting/before/enteranddeparting_before_vftf),

> FOR INDIAN NATIONALS
>
> Indian nationals are required to apply for visa to enter Singapore. Indian nationals holding official and diplomatic passports are exempted from the entry visa requirement. For other nationals, to find out if you require a visa to enter Singapore, you can contact the High Commission or visit the Immigration & Checkpoints Authority of Singapore website at www.ica.gov.sg
>
> Travellers at Singapore Changi Airport who are in transit and who are not seeking entry into Singapore, do not need to apply for a visa if they remain in the transit area.